# django - underscoring foreign keys - pros and cons

Tags: python, django, pep8

As PEP8 states, one should name classes that have several words with camelcase (e.g. `ProfileAttributeGroup`), and use underscores for variables (`profile_attribute_group`).

However when it comes to django and reverse relations (and templates), we are forced to use lowercased name of classes.

For example, if our `ProfileAttributeGroup` has a one-to-one key to a `Profile` model, the reverse lookup would be `profile.profileattributegroup`.

Okay, we can override that one; but this lowercasing also happens in `DetailView` and `UpdateView` templates and in sql joins (e.g. `someattr.filter(profileattributegroup__isnull=False)`), and there's nothing we can do about it.

This makes me think that it makes sense to just lowercase foreign key names, without adding any underscores there. This way I won't have to remember when to use `profile_attribute_group` or `profileattributegroup`.

But explicit ignoring of underscores contradicts PEP8.

My question is, has anyone else had my doubts? And are there any future downsides of ignoring underscores that I haven't thought about?

Comment: I don't get your reasoning. Django defines foreign keys as **fields**, hence you should follow the convention for fields, i.e. lowercase_with_underscore. Or are you writing code like `class Person(Model): WeirdNameWithCaps = SomeField(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

There certainly is something you can do about it, if it bothers you that much. All relationship fields that automatically define a reverse relation also allow you to override that default by specifying `related_name`. So if you really don't like `profile.profileattributegroup`, define the one-to-one field with `related_name='profile_attribute_group'`.